# Can I use 127.0.0.2, 3, etc to map docker container ports to the same port but different loopback IP on my docker host?

Tags: linux, docker, linux-networking, docker-compose, docker-networking

I am using ubuntu 22.04 as docker host. On this host I deploy an nginx reverse proxy with TLS termination.I will deploy multiple (say 3) docker compose deployments on that host, and each one there will be a web application listen on 80. The trivial solution is use

```
# in my docker compose for different services:
127.0.0.1:8081:80 # in the first deployment
...
127.0.0.1:8082:80 # in the second deployment
...
127.0.0.1:8083:80 # in the third deployment
```

and configure nginx server blocks accordingly.

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
etc
```

My question that **instead of the working solution above, can I** do by this utilizing 127.0.0.x addresses on the 127.0.0.0/8 subnet like this:

(Besides I could simply try this as POC instead of asking here, my question is **what could be the drawback or hidden trap using this not so conventional method instead the more mainstream method?** I mean is the full 127.0.0.0/8 subnet garanted working in any linux, also is this compatible with docker container port mapping, etc)

```
# in my docker compose for different services:
127.0.0.1:8080:80 # in the first deployment
...
127.0.0.2:8080:80 # in the second deployment
...
127.0.0.3:8080:80 # in the third deployment
```

and configure nginx server blocks accordingly.

```
# in my nginx.conf for different server blocks
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
...
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.2:8080;
```

Comment: The short answer is "yes".

Comment: And the long answer is "yes, and why not just try?"

Comment: And a longer is answer still is that you need to provision additional loopback devices and change the netmask for 127.0.0.0 (default is 8 bits) or additional routing rules or add aliases on the current device (and add routing rules). But the elephant in the room is WHY? WHAT ARE YOU TRYING TO ACHIEVE?

Comment: @symcbean, there will be 10 docker compose and 10 web service each of them. The 10 compose are totally independent, and each of them will have 10 nodes for load balancing. I can map the ports like 80 - 180, but seems to be more organized to map them 127.0.0.1 :80-89, 127.0.0.2:80-89, etc

Comment: I don't know why it "seems" to be more organized doing it this way - it is *very* complicated to implement.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can and for the whole /8 subnet if you want to do it

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it, but if you have routing requirements in the future it will be quite difficult because everything is running on the "front-end" site is running on one ip.

Comment: nginx is listening to the outside, and will reverse proxy by host header to different loopback addresses